# "The Clean Architecture" blog post: Why Entities do not cross boundaries?

Tags: architecture, clean-architecture

In Robert C. Martin's [post](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html) the statement (emphasis mine)

> The important thing is that isolated, simple, data structures are passed across the boundaries. **We don’t want to cheat and pass *Entities*** or Database rows.

confuses me. Clearly, the inner layers must not about the existence of a *RowStructure* object defined within in a DB API in the outer layer, e.g., but why are *Entities* not allowed to cross boundaries upwards? Isn't exactly this boundary crossing of *Entities* indicated by the arrows in the Clean Architecture diagram (application business rules, interface adapters use *Entities*, so *Entities* are "crossing" the boundaries).

Or am I somehow confusing "method calls" with "boundary crossing of data" here? (But what does "crossing" mean then?).

Answer (score 1):

Entities should not be transferred to outer layers because that would create coupling, and as an effect, testing will be impacted.

You want entities to be completely isolated, in order to remove the need for their change when other layers get changed.

So the solution is to use flat models in contracts between the layers, because they are easier to mange during testing. One small downside would be that you always need to convert between different contracts (which is manageable), but the big win is that you got a clear contract, which is valuable on the long run, as the code evolves.

Comment: I'd like to know more about flat moel, do you have any good resources?

Answer (score -1):

Entities compose a domain, which should remain isolated from the outside world. The interface adapters are here to help us achieve such isolation, in several ways:

**First**, by mediating client requests into application circle (use cases) through the input port, which requires such requests to be plain (and not domain entities);

**Second**, by mediating entities back to the client through the output port, i.e. transforming entities into DTOs (data transfer objects);

**Third**, by transforming entities into persistence objects to be sent to some database.

And that is exactly the meaning of entities not crossing the boundaries.

Comment: When you argue in terms of DTOs, you have a DB heavy and or web application in mind, I guess. My programs are none of these. Further, Martin writes (about the Interface Adapters layer): "[...] data is converted, in this layer, from the form most convenient for entities and use cases, into the form most convenient for whatever persistence framework is being used [...]". It sounds as if not the entities themselves would represents the data being transformed to/from DTOs (your second comment); Entities seem to be the clients of DTOs or data structures.

Comment: I actually did not mention any kind of application/DB, whether it is a monolith or a microservice is not matter. I cannot think of entities as "clients" in any way, entities are simply core objects that form a business domain and therefore should be converted to persistence objects (an entity might contain several properties which are useful for core logics without the need to be persisted).